# Assignment allocation (linear programming) lookalike

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I have job that needs to be done in 14 days. I have 5 workers. One day need exactly 3 workers. Each worker can only work maximum 9 days. Each worker has their day preference, each day for each worker has different cost.

Now, how do I solve this in mathematics term? How do I find the lowest cost possible for the worker assignment?

I don't think this is assignment problem since the Hungarian algorithm is designed so that I can only find 1-to-1 assignment. (In this case, 1 worker for 1 day)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to solve this problem is an **IP (Integer Programming) formulation.** Your intuition is right, this is very similar to an assignment problem -- we are essentially assigning workers to work on certain days.

Here are the steps to formulate the problem:

**Decision variable**: (In English) Which worker works on which days?

Let's label the days **t** (1..14)
And the workers **w1 to w5**.

So,

`X_wt = 1 if worker w works on day t`

`X_wt = 0 otherwise`

The constraints are now fairly straight forward to write down.
Each day needs exactly 3 workers.

```
X_1t + X_2t + X_3t + X_4t + X_5t = 3 for each t (1..14)
```

Each worker can work for a maximum of 9 days:

```
(sum over t=1..14) X_wt <= 9 for each w (1..5)
```

And finally, the **Objective function**:

Let `C_wt` be the cost of hiring worker w on day t. With a double summation:

```
Min (sum over w 1..5)(sum over t 1..14) C_wt
```

And in order to accommodate worker preferences for days,
you can layer on yet another set of costs, say `P_wt`.

That's the basic formulation. You will then need an IP/LP solver (such as `CPLEX` or `Excel Solver` or R's `optim` library) to get the actual solution.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved as a [minimum-cost network-flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) problem on a bipartite graph.  Each worker represents a source with a supply of 9 units, and each day represents a sink with demand of 3.  The arcs between the supply and demand each have capacity 1, and a cost corresponding to their preference to be off on that day.  If there is flow along an arc, that means that a particular worker should be working that day.

Although this can't be solved with a Hungarian method, but with several fast algorithms, including [network simplex](http://www.me.utexas.edu/~jensen/models/network/net8.html).

Algebraically, the formulation is

```
minimize sum_w sum_d p_wd x_wd
subject to
\sum_w x_wd = 3    forall d
\sum_d x_wd <= 5   forall w
```

if p_wd is worker w's preference for day d.  This is a [totally unimodular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_unimodularity) constraint matrix, so it does not require a mixed-integer solver.

Comment: Hmm. This seems close. But how do you decide which 3 to assign out of the 5 available workers?

Sorry, I'm still new in Operation Research, never learned all these during university years. Now I'm self-learning.

Comment: @user1491884 The network-simplex algorithm will give you a flow satisfying the demand at each sink node and not exceeding the capacity at each source node at a minimum cost.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a bin-packing and tsp problem. Look for capacited vehicle routing problem. It shares many problems but you have exactly 3 workers. In capacited vehicle routing there is x workers. It think you need more information.